# How to fix issue on mac/linux for error: Decoded string is not a valid IDN name for .Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

So on mac osx I was attempting to run a simple call to download a youtube mp4 and when trying to download the video using the following code:

```
class Downloader
{
    public static async void Download(string url)
    {
        using(var client = new WebClient())
        {
            await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, "example.mp4");
        }
    }

}
```

Called the method inside main like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "";

        Downloader.Download(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
```

Then I got the following exception

```
---- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
-------- System.ArgumentException : Decoded string is not a valid IDN name.
Parameter name: unicode
```

Comment: Possibly related: [\[HttpClient\] SSL Idn decode failure](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29703)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to add the following at the beginning of your code (preferably in the main method):

`AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);`

Microsoft made some changes where they [replaced the default HttpMessageHandler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/11/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-2/#user-content-sockets-performance-and-socketshttphandler) with their new implementation for speed.

> We built a new from-the-ground-up managed HttpMessageHandler called
>   SocketsHttpHandler. It’s an implementation of HttpMessageHandler based
>   on .NET sockets and Span.
>
> SocketsHttpHandler is now the default implementation for HttpClient.
>   The biggest win of SocketsHttpHandler is performance. It is a lot
>   faster than the existing implementation. There are other benefits,
>   such as:
>
> - Elimination of platform dependencies on libcurl (for Linux and the macOS) and WinHTTP (for Windows) – simplifying both development,
>     deployment, and servicing.
> - Consistent behavior across platforms and platform/dependency versions.